# Ncurses с кодировкой cp866. Выводит заглавные русские символы как два символа, тильда(~) и заглавная латинская

Tags: c, ncurses

Есть древний как помёт мамонта софт, писаный на С с использованием curses под SCO-Unix и кодировку cp866. Я пытаюсь перенести его на linux (SLES 12) в связи понятно с чем. Вместо curses(которую тупо не нашел) при компиляции использую ncurses. И вроде все работает, но вот есть один косяк конкретно с заглавными русскими буквами - он их отображает вот так:

```
~Qтолбец:1
```

вместо

```
Столбец:1
```

Код:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "curses.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    initscr();
    mvaddstr(1, 0,
              "Тут текст в кодировке cp866.");
    getch();
}
```

Выводит:

```
~Rут текст в кодировке cp866.
```

Если весь тот-же текст параллельно выводить `printf`'ом, то выводится корректная строка.

Comment: @rjhdby Используйте библиотеку `ncursesw` для корректного отображения кодировки UTF-8. И если Вы подгружаете весь текст из БД. Или БД конвертируйте в UTF-8 или в программе преобразуйте cp866 в UTF-8.

Comment: @rjhdby Для корректного отображения кодировки cp866 нужно настроить не только  консоль и программу но и Вашу программу эмулятора консоли (xterm konsole etc). Эмуляторы консоли работают со шрифтами то нужен шрифт поддерживающий именно кодировку  cp866. Проще перевести в UTF-8.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Для исправления данной ситуации надо добавить вызов функции [use_legacy_coding(2);](https://linux.die.net/man/3/use_legacy_coding) после `initscr();`

> the parameter is in the range 128-159, i.e., a C1 control code. If
>   use_legacy_coding has been called with a 2 parameter, unctrl returns
>   the parameter, i.e., a one-character string with the parameter as the
>   first character. Otherwise, it returns ''~@'', ''~A'', etc., analogous
>   to ''^@'', ''^A'', C0 controls.

Такой код корректно отображает текст в однобайтовой восьмибитной кодировке CP866:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "curses.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    initscr();
    use_legacy_coding(2);
    mvaddstr(1, 0,
              "Тут текст в кодировке cp866.");
    getch();
}
```